# How to utilize my Bluetooth headphone controls

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I'm running Kubuntu 22.04 and I have a set of MPOW Bluetooth headphones.  (I also have a set of Bose headphones, but I think the issue is the same for either.) The headphones have a built-in volume control and also a built-in stop-start button on the side of the headset.  I would like to be able to use these controls while listening to music, since I'm not right in front of my computer.

I have two different ways of playing music: the Clementine player and the Audio Station app on my Synology NAS.  However, the headset controls don't seem to affect the sound when I use either of these. I've also installed **kmix**, but it doesn't seem to be helpful.

Apparently there is some work going on with Pipewire, but it's not clear what the status is with respect to Pulseaudio, which is what I'm using. My experience with Pipewire was not good.

So how can I utilize my headset controls in Ubuntu? Or do I need to turn to Windows?

Comment: How NAS is not working with the headphones either is not info that helps with the Ubuntu issue. BUT it does point out that what you are trying to do is not supported. Did you check the makers web site and see f they have any apps and or drivers for this device?

Comment: The Synology NAS does work with the headphones, in that I can run the Audio Station app and play music theugh the headphones.  What I can't do is to use the headphone controls to control the volume and start/stop the music.  The MPOW website has no helpful information. Bose seems to be more concerned with supporting stuff like Alexa and telephony and less concerned with thus kind of direct control.